# How to add image UIImage with indent in UITextField in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in which I want to add an image on the left side. I do this using `UIImageView` which is set in `leftView` property of `UITextField`. The image is resized in Image View to proper size. The problem is that it is stick to the border. How can I set left indent of the image. I suppose that one solution is to set some blank space in the left side of the image, but I want to use indent. Also I want some indent after the image, so the text is not so close to it.

I use following code:

```
[textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 20)];
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom_image"];
textField.leftView = imageView1;
```

Comment: instead of sub viewing,place that text filed(without border) on an image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need subclass UITextField and implement in it

`- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds`

Answer (score 12):

You can set the UIImageview frame more than the original UIImage and set the UIImageview contentMode property to centre.
 Please refer below answer.

```
UIImageView *imgSearch=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 28)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
[imgSearch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"]];

[imgSearch setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre

self.tfSearch.leftView=imgSearch;
self.tfSearch.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a subclass UITextField and overrides

```
- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

These will change the rect for the leftView .